# How do I run a command from a base64 encoded string in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to run a command from a base64 encoded string in bash. For example `bHMgLWwgLwo=` would be equal to `ls -l`. How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011572/decode-from-base64-and-execute-command ? (related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/178521/how-can-i-decode-a-base64-string-from-the-command-line )

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Not exactly, I want to decode a string and run that decoded string. I found a solution though I’ll post as an answer shortly.

Comment: But that is exactly what the first link is - "*How can I decode base64 string on Linux command and then execute the decoded string?*" - isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

You can run a base64 encoded string in bash by piping the output of the base64 package for coreutils to bash. For example the command `base64 -D <<< bHMgLWwgLwo= | sh` would run the command `ls -l`.

Comment: on my version the option is `-d`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with bypassing the special characters.

`echo bHMgLWwgLwo= | base64 -d | sh`